# Understanding mutating functions with the self property

Tags: ios, macos, swift

I'm working through Apple's Swift Programming Language book and came across the following example.  I want to make sure I have the concept correct before continuing.

```
struct Point {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
    mutating func moveByX(deltaX: Double, deltaY: Double) {
        self = Point(x: x + deltaX, y: y + deltaY)
    }
}
```

The book states "the moveByX function creates a brand new structure who's x and y values are to the target location."

So, if I do this;

```
var myPoint = Point(x: 1, y: 1)
myPoint.moveByX(2, deltaY: 2)
```

My understanding is Swift releases the myPoint struct with the values 1, 1 from memory, and it is no longer available.  In its place a new one is created with the values 3, 3.  Am I right?

Comment: var myPoint will become a Point with x=3 and y=3. What else is there to know? :)

Comment: From my limited knowledge of Obj-C and iOS I was concerned about memory management.  I realize that in this example that wouldn't be an issue but in the past things like dealloc and reference counting made my head spin and was one of the things that humbled me and made me walk away from learning Obj-C.  It is my understanding that Swift eliminates a lot of this but I want to make sure my understanding is correct.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be precise values 1 and 1 are replaced by 3, 3. Location in memory is the same in both cases and allocated when particular instance is allocated.